# "predictions of" or "predictions for"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

As far as I know, both are grammatically correct, so which one is best to use?

> My predictions of the future

Or:

> My predictions for the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use **predictions of the future**. Also some people use "about" after prediction. We use "prediction for" usually before an event.

Example:

> **Predictions of** the future are not reliable.
>
> 2011 **Predictions for** world events.